# How do you output taxonomy terms and the fields thats attached to it?

Tags: 7, views

I have the following issue where I want to output a list of taxonomy terms and the fields it contains. I have a list of taxonomy terms as US States and each term has a field called city. How can I display the State and City in Drupal 7 Views 3?

I added the field **All taxonomy terms** and I dont' see any option to display its fields in anyway.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add these 2 fields to your view (and remove the "all taxonomy terms" field you've already added):

```
 Taxonomy term: Name

 Taxonomy term: City
```

Your precise field names may vary.

I was able to do a test view like this and State and City display OK.

I'm not doing any fancy relationships or anything with the view. If you don't see these fields as options, it may be we have different modules, but I'm also Drupal 7 views 3.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the **Content: Taxonomy terms on nodes** relationship in your content view. After that you will be able to choose the city field of your state term in the Fields section of the view.